# Envio de informações por getJSON

Tags: getjson

Tenho um redirecionamento por getJSON, porém faz alguns dias que parou de funcionar para uma tela, não consigo encontrar o erro.
Se eu colocar um alert ou um redirecionamento assim : $(location).attr('href', 'http://sendCobranca.php'); 
 Funciona, mas preciso passar alguns parâmetros

```
$(document).on('click','[name="cobranca"]',function(){
        var tipo = $(this).attr('tipo-cobranca');
        var form = {}
        form['ids'] =  getCheckedValues($('.ck:checked'));
        form['tipo'] = tipo;
         $.getJSON('sendCobranca.php',
            {
                form: form
            },

            function(j){
                if(j){

                }
            });

        // console.log(form);               
    });
```

Comment: Podes explicar melhor _"parou de funcionar"_? mostra algum erro? o ajax chega a ser enviado?

Comment: Não apresenta erro, não acontece nada, para testar o botão do form, eu coloquei um alerta, ai sim exibe o alerta, então pensei que poderia ser problema na outra pagina, coloquei um echo "testestsetsetse";
Mas não exibia, então fiz um redirecionamento e vai para a outra pagina.
somente neste getJSON que não acontece nada.